# Android SearchView not working when calling invalidateOptionsMenu()

Tags: android, show-hide, searchview, submenu

I want to hide some menu items when the search view expands so this is the code I used:

```
@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    menu.findItem(R.id.action_refresh).setVisible(!isSearchOpen)
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    MenuItem searchMenuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search)
    SearchView searchView = searchMenuItem.getMenu();

    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this);

    MenuItemCompat.setOnActionExpandListener(searchMenuItem, new MenuItemCompat.OnActionExpandListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onMenuItemActionCollapse(MenuItem item) {
            isSearchOpen = true;
            invalidateOptionsMenu();

            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onMenuItemActionExpand(MenuItem item) {
            isSearchOpen = false;
            invalidateOptionsMenu();
            return true;
        }
    });
}
```

Now this code works as expected except for one issue: when I click the search button, the SearchView does not appear. I cannot figure out what is the problem. I searched for similar issues on stack overflow but I didn't found any answer the fixed the issue, so any help will be welcomed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can **try this** way to hide and show other options menu:-

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.search_menu, menu);
    final  MenuItem delMenu = menu.findItem(R.id.action_delete);
    final  MenuItem editMenu = menu.findItem(R.id.action_edit);
    MenuItem searchMenu = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
    SearchView searchView = (SearchView) searchMenu.getActionView();

    searchView.setOnQueryTextFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View view, boolean b) {
            if(b) {
                delMenu.setVisible(false);
                editMenu.setVisible(false);
            }
        }
    });
    searchView.setOnCloseListener(new SearchView.OnCloseListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onClose() {
            delMenu.setVisible(true);
            editMenu.setVisible(true);
            return false;
        }
    });
    return true;
}
```